# IIS .NET Framework, ASP.NET Version Mismatch

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have a .NET 4.0 web application which uses an asp gridview control to display data. The control will automatically sort data when a column header is clicked. I have this application running and sorting fine on both a dev and test server. However, on the prod server, it does not sort correctly. No error is thrown, it just does not act correctly. Since the code is identical I believe this has to be an environment issue.

When trying to troubleshoot this issue, I deliberately malformed the web.config in both environments and noticed the following difference when the error page is displayed:

Dev (code works as expected):

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249
```

Prod (code does not work as expected):

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0
```

Could this be the cause of the issue? What exactly does this signify? Trying to find this answer on my own has proved fruitless. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the client side for an error? You should probably create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I've done fiddler captures for both servers performing the same actions. Nothing out of the ordinary. I just got done comparing the raw outputs to see if it would give me any clues but no luck. I'm going to take your advice and make a simple page with a gridview of static data.

Comment: Fiddler won't capture client side errors. You need to check your browser's JavaScript debug console to see those.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I've tried that as well. No JS errors.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0. When updating the dev server to match this version, the gridview does not sort correctly. I'm uncertain as to whether or not this is a bug in ASP.NET or a fix for a bug which was exploited by the code. Regardless, the original issue was caused by difference in ASP.NET versions.